# Update progress bar in with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to update my progress bar in html while function is running. Is there any way I can do this?

```
function animateProgressBar() {
  var numIteration = 100;

  for (var i = 1; i <= numIteration; i++) {
    //do some calculations
    width = (i/numIteration)*100;
    htmlElement.style.width = width + '%'; 
  }
}
```

Comment: You simply want the width to go from 0% to 100%? Or there is some associated event with it?

Comment: This piece of code isn't enough at all ..You should provide all the related code (html , css , js) .. or create a demo/snippet to let us know where your problem is.. And why you tagged jquery while your code in a pure js??

Comment: **MESSAGE TO THE OP EDITOR** please don't edit the OP tags before you know exactly what OP need .. specially javascript and jquery tags may be OP needs a solution on both javascript and jquery

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, Calculation inside the loop takes long time. I want to provide information on the page about progress. But I can't pause the loop and change html element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code is blocking. Therefore the page isnt rendered, and the status bar doesnt change. You may use a setTimeout recursively:

```
function animateProgressBar(numIteration,index=1) {
    width = (index/numIteration)*100;
    htmlElement.style.width = width + '%'; 
    if(index<numIteration) setTimeout(animateProgressBar,100,numIteration,index+1);
}
```

Start like this:

```
animateProgressBar(100); // from 1 to 100
```

Note that *index=1* in the parameters is ES6, so just use it on modern browsers...

Comment: @sheriffderek yep added a sidenote

Comment: @Jonas w, thank you for answer, the thing is that i can't call the function _animateProgressBar_ inside the _for_  loop. The function starts only when loop finishes. Does js allows you only one thread at time?

Comment: @pandaBaer exactly. Thats why heavy calculations are interrupted with setTimeouts so that other things (ui rendering, user interaction ) can occur

Comment: @pandaBaer you may put your heavy calculations in a loop like the above...

Comment: @Jonasw I still can't update progress bar, my progress bar starts with work when for loop ends.

Comment: @pandaBaer: dont use a for loop! This is blocking and creates a bad user experience. However im not able to help you with that as you didnt post the neccessary code....